# Gravitational motion of 2 point masses in free space

Tags: general-relativity

I came across this question:

**"If there are two point masses in free space(i.e., there is no other mass/force/field acting in their vicinity), will those two point masses get closer to each other, or will they remain stationary as they are?"**

I approached this question through Newtonian Gravitation, and I thought they would come closer to each other. But the answer was that they would remain stationary, the way they are, and not move closer towards each other. It is a drawback of Newtonian theory, and I was supposed to approach it through General Relativity.

I have thought a lot about it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Any solution, approached through general relativity, helping me out with this will be appreciated.

**Note:** There is a possibility that the answer is wrong. I'm not sure. Please help.

Comment: Could you please cite the source?

Comment: It is from a mock interview. That's why I said I'm not sure if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if the two masses do not circle with the right speed around their center of mass, the will move to get closer to each other, in no case they will stay at there initial distance. So the statement you heard is false.
trula